# Converting mobile first to desktop first media queries, not sure if I did it right

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm building an app primarily for desktop, so I tried to convert Bootstrap's `min-width` (mobile first) to `max-width` (desktop first), but not sure if they're functionally identical.

That's my goal, to make them do the exact same thing at the exact same pixel breakpoints.

Can any CSS gurus out there tell me if these are identical? The `max-width` 1-pixel difference is messing with my brain, and I have no confidence with media queries at this point.

```
/* 1. Mobile first, do your .default stuff below 575 without a media query */

.default-reference {...}        /*    0 -  575 */
@media (min-width: 576px){...}  /*  576 -  767 */
@media (min-width: 768px){...}  /*  768 -  991 */
@media (min-width: 992px){...}  /*  992 - 1199 */
@media (min-width: 1200px){...} /* 1200 - 1399 */
@media (min-width: 1400px){...} /*     >= 1400 */

/* 2. Desktop first, do your .default stuff above 1400 without a media query */

.default-reference {...}        /*     >= 1400 */
@media (max-width: 1399px){...} /* 1200 - 1399 */
@media (max-width: 1199px){...} /*  992 - 1199 */
@media (max-width: 991px){...}  /*  768 -  991 */
@media (max-width: 767px){...}  /*  576 -  767 */
@media (max-width: 575px){...}  /*    0 -  575 */
```

Comment: I think that should work fine yes, i don't think the 1 pixel even matters ? alternatively you could also use the `not` operator to still use the `min-width` property (and values) you're used to from your mobile first version.

Comment: Your mq's will work as expected. As for whether they're identical... not sure that's important. Bootstrap (and all frameworks) use mq's that are arbitrary "based on common screen sizes" but we all know that common changes perpetually. The best media query is no media query.

Comment: yea, and i don't think many of the common situations result in the exact values they've chosen. if you type `document.documentElement.clientWidth` in your devtools console you'll likely get a value that isn't within <2px of any of the cutoff points.

Comment: Thanks all, my main hangup was the 1px difference. If someone wants to post an answer with maybe some additional insight, I'll give it the big ole green checkmark. EDIT: An example of where to put the `:not` operator would be interesting. Not sure where to put it.

Comment: posted it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pedantic version would be:

```
.default-reference {...}            /*     >= 1400 */
@media not (min-width: 1400px){...} /* 1200 - 1399 */
@media not (min-width: 1200px){...} /*  992 - 1199 */
@media not (min-width: 992px){...}  /*  768 -  991 */
@media not (min-width: 768px){...}  /*  576 -  767 */
@media not (min-width: 576px){...}  /*    0 -  575 */
```

But really the cutoff points aren't super-strategic exact values, they merely represent somewhat evenly distributed points along the spectrum which do a moderately decent job at classifying groups of common situations. Hence, worrying about potential `1px` offsets is likely a waste of time.

---

If you want a quick demonstration:

```
@media all                     { body { background-color: yellow; } body::before { content: 'xxl'; } } /*     >= 1400 */
@media not (min-width: 1400px) { body { background-color: blue;   } body::before { content: 'xl';  } } /* 1200 - 1399 */
@media not (min-width: 1200px) { body { background-color: purple; } body::before { content: 'lg';  } } /*  992 - 1199 */
@media not (min-width:  992px) { body { background-color: red;    } body::before { content: 'md';  } } /*  768 -  991 */
@media not (min-width:  768px) { body { background-color: green;  } body::before { content: 'sm';  } } /*  576 -  767 */
@media not (min-width:  576px) { body { background-color: orange; } body::before { content: 'xs';  } } /*    0 -  575 */
```